# Laravel lang slug in url

Tags: php, laravel

I've followed [this article](https://tjd-studio.com/blog/painless-laravel-multi-language-application) to add multi language into my app and it's working fine, the only issue i need to solve is that languages slug won't add to the url.

## Example

based on the article above i get my page in English like:

```
www.myapp.co/my-slug
```

and in another language the same (however translation will placed)

#### what i want is like:

```
www.myapp.co/en/my-slug

&

www.myapp.co/id/my-slug

etc.
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: So it means you somewhere missed some part of tutorial. Compare your code with tutorial

Comment: did u check this ? https://github.com/akaunting/language

Comment: my friend can you tell me... are you using url function?

Comment: @GautamPatadiya yes i have url like: `Route::get('/{lang}', 'Front\LanguageController@frontend')->name('lang.switch');`

Comment: @Justinas i checked it several times nothing related to the language slug.

Comment: @Bira i don't use that package, it's custom middleware

Comment: @mafortis I mean to ask you at a time when you are actually binding id with a tag or any other tag at a time try to use this function. like this:

<a href={{ url('your_url', $id) }}>Test</a>

Comment: @mafortis Did you solved this?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu no i didn't. :(

Comment: @mafortis check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921037/laravel-multi-language-routes-without-prefix it is simillar to what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I used [this tutorial](https://irando.co.id/articles/how-to-use-language-slug-in-laravel-url-and-set-directions) and it gets me what I needed

Comment: The tutorial link is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063329/3209381), where I used [mcamara's Laravel Localization package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) to achieve this. It was painless for me :)

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't wan't to use any package for translations is there any other way that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

Change your route using prefix

```
Route::prefix('{locale}')->group(function ($locale) {

    if (array_key_exists($locale, Config::get('languages'))) {
        Session::put('applocale', $locale);
    }
    // else return 404 
    Route::get('your-slug', function () {    
    });
});
```

Comment: If you mean I should placed this code to my middleware it doesn't work, beside that if i place this code around my handle codes then the does it get `$local` from? sorry but it's a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `App::getLocale()` as route group prefix and use that to choose language .

In routing

```
Route::middleware(App::getLocale())->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });
});
```

Retrieve the request parameters in middleware and if require 
In your middleware you can put something like a conditional and reconstruct the url if required and then redirect it to the newly constructed url.

```
$locale = $request->segment(1);

if (in_array($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
     \App::setLocale($locale);
            return $next($request);
} else {
    //
}
```

Comment: I tried it doesn't work, maybe you can be more specific how and where should i place that?

Comment: I am traveling, but the idea was add a middleware where you will receive this prefix and change the language.

Comment: @mafortis I have edited my answer, may be that make more sense.

Comment: @mafortis, set the locale as prefix, retrieve the locale in your middleware and then use it as required. let me know if you can not make it after this too.